# How to install readr package for R in Opensuse

Tags: r, installation, opensuse, readr

I try to install **readr** package for R. But I got a lot of errors and the package isn't installed.

My setup:

- **openSUSE Leap 15.4**  x86_64 **ICEWM**
- R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"
- RStudio 2023.06.0+421 "Mountain Hydrangea" Release (583b465ecc45e60ee9de085148cd2f9741cc5214, 2023-06-06) for OpenSUSE 15
- Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) rstudio/2023.06.0+421 Chrome/110.0.5481.208 Electron/23.3.0 Safari/537.36

---

I try to install from **xterm** and from **RStudio Terminal**:

```
install.package("readr")
```

log:

```
* installing *source* package ‘utf8’ ...
** package ‘utf8’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -I"/usr/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -Iutf8lite/src -fpic  -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -g  -c as_utf8.c -o as_utf8.o
/bin/sh: gcc: command not found
make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:168: as_utf8.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘utf8’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/utf8’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘utf8’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘bit’ ...
** package ‘bit’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -I"/usr/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -g  -c attrutil.c -o attrutil.o
/bin/sh: gcc: command not found
make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:168: attrutil.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘bit’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/bit’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘bit’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘glue’ ...
** package ‘glue’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -I"/usr/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -g  -c glue.c -o glue.o
/bin/sh: gcc: command not found
make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:168: glue.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘glue’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/glue’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘glue’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘fansi’ ...
** package ‘fansi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -I"/usr/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -g  -c assumptions.c -o assumptions.o
/bin/sh: gcc: command not found
make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:168: assumptions.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fansi’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/fansi’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘fansi’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘magrittr’ ...
** package ‘magrittr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -I"/usr/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -g  -c pipe.c -o pipe.o
/bin/sh: gcc: command not found
make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:168: pipe.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘magrittr’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/magrittr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘magrittr’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘cli’ ...
** package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -I"/usr/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -I../inst/include -fpic  -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -g  -c ansi.c -o ansi.o
/bin/sh: gcc: command not found
make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:168: ansi.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘cli’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/cli’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘cli’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘rlang’ ...
** package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -I"/usr/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./rlang/  -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -g  -c capture.c -o capture.o
/bin/sh: gcc: command not found
make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:168: capture.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/rlang’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘tzdb’ ...
** package ‘tzdb’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/usr/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/include  -I../inst/include -DINSTALL=dummy -DAUTO_DOWNLOAD=0 -DHAS_REMOTE_API=0 -DUSE_OS_TZDB=0 -DONLY_C_LOCALE=1 -fpic  -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -g  -c api.cpp -o api.o
/bin/sh: g++: command not found
make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:177: api.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘tzdb’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/tzdb’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tzdb’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘bit’ is not available for package ‘bit64’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/bit64’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘bit64’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘cli’, ‘glue’, ‘rlang’ are not available for package ‘lifecycle’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/lifecycle’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘cli’, ‘glue’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’ are not available for package ‘vctrs’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/vctrs’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘vctrs’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘cli’, ‘fansi’, ‘glue’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘utf8’, ‘vctrs’ are not available for package ‘pillar’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/pillar’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘cli’, ‘glue’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘vctrs’ are not available for package ‘tidyselect’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/tidyselect’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyselect’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘vctrs’ are not available for package ‘hms’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/hms’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘hms’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘hms’ is not available for package ‘progress’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/progress’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘progress’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘fansi’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘magrittr’, ‘pillar’, ‘rlang’, ‘vctrs’ are not available for package ‘tibble’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/tibble’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tibble’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘bit64’, ‘cli’, ‘glue’, ‘hms’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘tibble’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘tzdb’, ‘vctrs’, ‘progress’ are not available for package ‘vroom’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/vroom’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘vroom’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘cli’, ‘hms’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘tibble’, ‘vroom’, ‘tzdb’ are not available for package ‘readr’
* removing ‘/home/yevhen/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.1/readr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘readr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/Rtmp73mcvr/downloaded_packages’
>
```

Comment: you are missing the GNU compiler collection it includes a C-compiler that readr needs (gcc), as well as a c++ complier (g++).

Comment: Oh, thank you. Will try to install GNU compiler collection.

Comment: No problem, you will likely encounter this error in the future (ie missing dependencies, look out for the `xy: command not found` lines in the error) Check first if they are installed from terminal using `which g++` and maybe are under a different path than R expects.

Answer (score 0):

By the [user12256545](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12256545/user12256545) comment I installed GNU compiler collection with gcc and g++. For openSUSE I used zypper:

```
zypper install -t pattern devel_C_C++
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install it from opensuse repository

`sudo zypper install R-readr`

[Opensuse software repository]
https://software.opensuse.org/package/R-readr